# Shift html from later <tr>s to the first <tr> to have a single row

Tags: jquery, html, variables

```
<html><head>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<table border=1>
<tr><div id="addonlocation"></div></tr>
<tr><div id="addonmatter_1"><td>am1.1</td><td>am1.2</td><td>am1.3</td></div></tr>
<tr><div id="addonmatter_2"><td>am2.1</td><td>am2.2</td><td>am2.3</td></div></tr>
<tr><div id="addonmatter_3"><td>am3.1</td><td>am3.2</td><td>am3.3</td></div></tr>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ww=$(window).width();
    var addonmatter1=$("#addonmatter_1").html();
    var addonmatter2=$("#addonmatter_2").html();
    var addonmatter3=$("#addonmatter_3").html();
    var shifter= addonmatter1 + addonmatter2 + addonmatter3;
    if (ww<460) {$("#addonlocation").html(shifter)};
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now this is what I want: All the data (or text) inside the second, third and forth  should assemble after the first  to create a single row.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: ??? You will then have a row with many columns, and other rows with only a few... not very clear what you want actually ?

Comment: I want to place the html in other <tr>s into the first one, i.e. have only a Single row (with many columns)

Comment: The only allowed child for `<tr>` is `<td>`. Something like `<div>` is not allowed here and there is no need for it, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by looping through your tr's and removing them after you've added their content to a temporary variable. After adding all the tr's content to the variable, wrap them in a tr, and append the variable to the table.
http://jsfiddle.net/nRJqA/1/

```
var content = "";
$('tr').each(function(){
    content += $(this).html();
    $(this).remove();
});
content = '<tr>'+content+'</tr>';
$('table').append(content);
```